# Issue reading the text file for my text generator program

Tags: python, tensorflow

Trying to get my tensorflow program to read a text file I made called "outputtext.text"
The program is based on the following code found here https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/text_generation

However whenever I put down the path listed for it it returns a error saying invalid syntax on the read file line

```
import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np
import os
import time


text = open(C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\outputtext.txt, 'rb').read().decode(encoding='utf-8')
print(text[:250])
```

i'm very new to coding with this and i'm not sure what I've done wrong?

Comment: to be specific. The error happens on the 'C' of the text=open

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
text = open('C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\outputtext.txt', 'rb').read().decode(encoding='utf-8')
```

Note that I added quotes to the path name.